# Can you run test suites more than once in ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have many steps in my Spark ETL process and I have created Suites to test the functionality of each step and the output of my steps is the input of the next step.

However, I would like to create a test that runs through the ETL process twice for example:

*Raw Data >> ETL_Step_1 >> ETL_Step_2 >> ETL_Step_3 >> Delta Data >> ETL_Step_1 >> ETL_Step_2 >> ETL_Step_3*

I'm getting an error from the Reporter as it cannot run a Suite with the same name as one that has been run before (e.g. I cannot run a Suite called ETL_Step_1 twice). The problem goes away if duplicate the Suites and rename the duplicates to do the following:

*Raw Data >> ETL_Step_1 >> ETL_Step_2 >> ETL_Step_3 >> Delta Data >> ETL_Step_1_2 >> ETL_Step_2_2 >> ETL_Step_3_2*

Is there a better way to run my test without duplicating and renaming test suites?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all ETL steps into a Defintion (collection) and run them

```
import org.scalatest.FunSpec
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.fast.tests.DataFrameComparer
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.daria.sql.SparkSessionExt._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType}

 describe("etl collection") {

    it("can run etls that are organized in a map") {

      val sourceDF = spark.createDF(
        List(
          ("bob", 14),
          ("liz", 20)
        ), List(
          ("name", StringType, true),
          ("age", IntegerType, true)
        )
      )

    val etlDefinition = new EtlDefinition(
       name =  "example",
       sourceDF = sourceDF, // etl step 1
       transform = someTransform(), // etl step 2
       write = someWriter(), // etl step 3
      hidden = false
    )


      val etls = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, EtlDefinition]("example" -> etlDefinition)

      etls += ("ex2" -> etlDefinition)

      etls("example").process()

    }

}
```

Another option might be `eventually` from scalatest. A small example for eventually:

```scala
 Post("/something", body) ~> routes ~> check {
      response should be a pendingResponse

      eventually {
        Post("/something", body) ~> routes ~> check {
          response should be a expectedResponse
        }
      }
    }
```

And instead of Post you can call some method.

You can here [here](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-etl) and [scalatest](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.1.1/org/scalatest/concurrent/Eventually.html)

UPDATE:

```
it ("your definition") {
   eventually { Thread.sleep(50); step1() should be A // assertion }
   eventually { Thread.sleep(50); step2() should be B }
   eventually { Thread.sleep(50); step3() should be C }
}
```

you can make them nested if you wish

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response Bob. The thing is, I have a test Suite for each ETL step. So my first ETL step creates some parquet from some raw text files, I then have a Suite with some tests to check that the number of rows in the parquet files matches the raw text files.

Perhaps the eventually option is more suited to my problem?  I could test the initial ETL run and then have an eventually with a second ETL run?

Comment: what is the return type of ETL step in your case?

Comment: I was expecting that you have unit tests separately for each step and this is kind integration/test test to test how steps are integrated/functional. Thus, I would prefer the first example, that all steps are defined as a ETL definition then you when run process, all the steps can be tested. You can have separate test for different scenarios like: all seccuss, 1st step failed, 2nd step failed, 3rd step failed, etc